# How to Hide or show the class based on the input text field

Tags: jquery

For clearing the text inside a text field

i have put up a class by name clear

http://jsfiddle.net/Loa3go9w/1/

How to make the class (searchClear_btn) show only if the textinput has some data or else disappear the class ??

```
$("#devsearchinputtext").val('This is test');
$("#devsearchinputtext").after('<a class="searchClear_btn">Clear</a>');
$(document).on('click', '.searchClear_btn', function(event) {
  $("#devsearchinputtext").val('');
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
});
```

Could you please let me know how to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind `keyup` event and show button if input have text.

```
$("#devsearchinputtext").on('keyup', function(){
    $('.searchClear_btn').toggle(!!this.value && !!this.value.length)
}).trigger('keyup');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/eLrdofm6/)

Comment: If there is no data inside the text input i wan to hide the clear or else i want to show that .

Comment: Initially when i clear the content os text filed , the clear is still visibile

Comment: Weird I am not able to repro any of above statement. I have use `.trigger('keyup');` for initial check

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to listen for any input changes in the text field and check if the value of the textbox has a length greater than 0.

```
$('#devsearchinputtext').on('input',function(e){
   if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
      $(".searchClear_btn").hide();
   } else {
      $(".searchClear_btn").show();
   }
});
```

The `input` event is generally more effective than `keyup` because it also listens for events like copy and pasting.